# JQuery Autocomplete in MVC3

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry I'm very new to JQuery... I can't for the life of me figure out where my bug is. When I run this I don't get any results. When I check the error in Firefox and Chrome it points to the source line. I just can't see anything wrong.

Here's my script

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CustName').autocomplete({
            //Firefox points to a syntax error here
            source: @SqlHelper.getJSONArray("CustName", "dba.BillingInfo") 
        });

    });
</script>

<p>Customer Name @Html.TextBox("CustName")</p>
```

SqlHelper.getJsonArray is a method I'm using to return a JSON string. I've checked and double checked that it is in fact returning valid JSON.

```
    public static string getJSONArray(string column,string table)
    {            
        string qry = "SELECT DISTINCT " + column
                    + " FROM " + table
                    + " WHERE " + column + " is not null"
                    + " AND " + column + " <> ''"
                    + " ORDER BY 1";

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        SqlDataReader reader = execQry(qry);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return serializer.Serialize(result);
    }
```

[UPDATE]
Here is the syntax error firefox is spitting back:

```
source: $.parseJSON([&quot;Customer1&quot;,&quot;Customer2...
---------------------^
```

So I'm beginning to think the issue is the quotes are getting rendered as quot; instead of ". If I try putting my source as ["Test1","Test2","Test3"] it works fine. Is there a way to get razor to not HTML encode the string?

[UPDATE]
That was the issue. The solution was using Html.Raw()

The issue was razor automatically HTML encoding the JSON. The fix is using HTML.Raw

```
$('#CustName').autocomplete({
    source: @Html.Raw(SqlHelper.getJSONArray("CustName", "dba.BillingInfo")) 
});
```

Comment: And what is the json returned by your method ? What is the rendered output ?

Comment: @DidierGhys Here's an example of the JSON output ["Customer1","Customer2","Customer3"]

Comment: @DidierGhys And the line Firefox has $('#CustName').autocomplete({
            source: [&quot;Customer1&quot;,&quot;Customer2&quot;,&quot;Customer3&quot;]
        });

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.parseJSON`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#CustName').autocomplete({
       //Firefox points to a syntax error here
      source: $.parseJSON(@SqlHelper.getJSONArray("CustName", "dba.BillingInfo"))
   });
});
```